# Where can I find a stand-alone Flash player install?

Tags: flash-player

I don't like the Adobe download manager installing. I want to just download the program and install it. I have several systems so is it the same for each one?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/436870/where-to-download-flash-player-newest-version-for-offline-installation?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to search “troubleshoot flash install” which would lead me to a document that had the links, but recently when I did that, the links were gone. Well, apparently Adobe FINALLY heard us that we HATE the download manager, and now when you go to the regular Adobe Flash download page, it is just the executable again. They JUST made the change back with the latest release.

There are two separate downloads depending on if you have IE (ActiveX) or Firefox (Plugin).

Comment: P.S. What made me realize this was going to http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/plugincheck/ to make sure my plugins were up-to-date. When I updated flash, it did not use the DLM. I mention it because that is a great site to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Adobe support page here: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/support/index.html

On the bottom of the page you will see 2 links. The 1st one is for IE only, the 2nd one is for all other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

[All on one page Here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html)